# Unique values in multidimensional array

Tags: groovy, multidimensional-array, unique-values

I am looking for a way to remove duplicated values from a multidimensional array

**Example**

```
String[][] values = [["A","A"],["A","A"],["B","B"],["B","B"]]

String[][] dupsRemoved = ?

println dupsRemoved
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
[["A","A"],["B","B"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
String[][] dupsRemoved = values.toList().unique()
```

Any reason you're using String arrays?  Embrace the lists ;-)

```
List values = [["A","A"],["A","A"],["B","B"],["B","B"]]

List dupsRemoved = values.unique()

println dupsRemoved
```

Comment: My god, how simple and nice solution!! :)